# What is webkit 1 way of createobjecturl?

Tags: javascript, webkit, blob

I tested `URL.createobjecturl` in chrome browser with large blob object and it worked like charm.
But problem came when I ran same code on older webkit (version 1), which is used in smaller devices.

I have tried while loop and in that String.fromCharCode.

```js
while (i--) {
   binaryString[i] = String.fromCharCode(blob[i]);
}
```

But it is taking 5-6 seconds as my blob size is 50000+.

Can anyone help me with optimized way of doing this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you aware that chrome is not webkit anymore?

Comment: yes I am, i wrote my code locally and tested on chrome. it works also. can you suggest alternative of this for webkit 1 ?